# Transição com ancoras em single page applications

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Como posso implementar um efeito de transição scroll suave através de âncoras, utilizando Jquery?

O template abaixo mostra um exemplo de uma transição scroll que estou buscando.

> http://www.aimyapp.com/

Gostaria de entender o efeito, e por este motivo estou procurando um entendimento utilizando JQuery, mas existe alguma biblioteca javascript que já faz este processo?

Comment: parece-me que sim. Mas caso não seja, e fundamentes porque, retiro o meu voto :)

Answer (score 1):

Existe esse complemento para o jQuery que faz exatamente o que você deseja:
https://github.com/flesler/jquery.scrollTo

Versão de demonstração: http://demos.flesler.com/jquery/scrollTo/